# GPS heading in Python

Tags: python, gps, heading

I am working on a GPS project in Python and need some help. I can't figure out how to get the heading part to work. I want the statement to be true with a heading of e.g. `355` degrees +/- a bit of error.  My problem is getting around `360` degrees. Like

```
if ((heading – headerror) % 360) <= Gps.heading <= ((heading + headerror) % 360):
```

if I use a heading of `355` with error of `20` and the gps reads `4` , which are both about north.

```
335 <= 4 <= 15
```

How can I get it to check if it's in a range of `335` to `15` which would really be `335` to `360`, `0` to `15`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple implementation:

```
def between(head, low, high):
    """Whether the heading head is between headings low and high."""
    head, low, high = map(lambda x: x % 360, (head, low, high))
    if high >= low:
        return low <= head <= high
    return low <= head < 360 or 0 <= head <= high
```

First it converts all arguments to headings between `0` and `360`, then it determines which situation we're in, whether we can do a simple comparison, or need to account for `0`/`360`. In the latter case, it explicitly checks between the `low` value and `360` and between `0` and the `high` value.

In use:

```
>>> between(4, 355-20, 355+20)
True
```

You could refactor this to use it like e.g. `equal(4, 355, 20)` if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Seeing what you did seems simple enough, I can even understand it. Although, I don’t think I could have figure it out on my own.  Now just to make sure it works in the field and not just the laptop.